# Dos ficheros diferentes columnas unirlas

Tags: python, pandas

tengo dos ficheros excel muy parecidos que quiero unir con los datos de ambos, pero en los ficheros los mismo valores están en diferentes columnas y uno tiene una columna extra, os dejo el código ya que no consigo hacerlo de ninguna manera y concatenando ambos me no me coloca los ids por ejemplo donde corresponde y me lo desplaza de columna ya que el primero fichero esta en la B y en el segundo esta en la A.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('Ordenados.xlsx', sheet_name='Reorder', header=None, skiprows=3, usecols="A:E")
df2 = pd.read_excel('Fixture.xlsx', sheet_name='Fixture list', header=None, skiprows=4, usecols="A:C,E,H")


print(df1.columns)
print(df2.columns)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
print(df2)

join = pd.concat([df1, df2])

print(join)
```

Answer (score 2):

Para unir 2 dataframes por una columna en el primero y otra en el segundo, puedes usar la función `merge`.

Teniendo estos dataframes de ejemplo:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "A": ["clave1", "clave2", "clave3"],
        "C": ["valor1", "valor2", "valor3"]
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "B": ["clave3", "clave1", "clave4"],
        "D": ["valor4", "valor5", "valor6"]
    }
)
```

`df1` quedaría así:

```
        A       C
0  clave1  valor1
1  clave2  valor2
2  clave3  valor3
```

`df2` quedaría así:

```
        B       D
0  clave3  valor4
1  clave1  valor5
2  clave4  valor6
```

Para unir `df1` y `df2` a través de las columnas **A** y **B** respectivamente, puedes usar la función `merge`. Tienes las siguientes opciones:

#### Left Merge

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="left", left_on="A", right_on="B")
```

`df3` queda así:

```
        A       C       B       D
0  clave1  valor1  clave1  valor5
1  clave2  valor2     NaN     NaN
2  clave3  valor3  clave3  valor4
```

`df3` es un nuevo dataframe con las columnas de `df1` y `df2` y con todas las filas de `df1`. En el caso de que un valor de **A** no se encuentre en **B**, los valores de las columnas de `df2` quedan como `NaN` (nulo).

#### Right Merge

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="right", left_on="A", right_on="B")
```

`df3` queda así:

```
        A       C       B       D
0  clave1  valor1  clave1  valor5
1  clave3  valor3  clave3  valor4
2     NaN     NaN  clave4  valor6
```

`df3` es un nuevo dataframe con las columnas de `df1` y `df2` y con todas las filas de `df2`. En el caso de que un valor de **B** no se encuentre en **A**, los valores de las columnas de `df1` quedan como `NaN`.

#### Inner Merge

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="inner", left_on="A", right_on="B")
```

`df3` queda así:

```
        A       C       B       D
0  clave1  valor1  clave1  valor5
1  clave3  valor3  clave3  valor4
```

`df3` es un nuevo dataframe con las columnas de `df1` y `df2` y sólo con las filas de `df1` y `df2` donde los valores de `A` y `B` coincidan. En el caso de que un valor de **A** no se encuentre en **B** o viceversa, dichas filas no aparecen en `df3`.

#### Outer Merge

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", left_on="A", right_on="B")
```

`df3` queda así:

```
        A       C       B       D
0  clave1  valor1  clave1  valor5
1  clave2  valor2     NaN     NaN
2  clave3  valor3  clave3  valor4
3     NaN     NaN  clave4  valor6
```

`df3` es un nuevo dataframe con las columnas de `df1` y `df2` y con todas las filas de `df1` y `df2`. En el caso de que un valor de **A** no se encuentre en **B**, los valores de las columnas de `df2` quedan como `NaN`, y viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

Si los dos dataframes tienen las mismas dimensiones lo más conveniente (en mi opinión), es usar el función [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

> Concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis with optional set logic along the other axes.

Siendo más específicos en el axis 1:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)
```

**¿Cómo se usa?**

`concate()` es una función definida en pandas, **no es un método de un objeto dataframe**. Se requiere pasar como argumento una lista con los elementos a concatenar y el axis en base cual se desea hacer la concatenación. **Si tus dataframes son de diferente longitud es más conveniente usar otros métodos**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2),columns = ["A","B"]) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2),columns = ["C","D"])
print("{} \n".format(df1))
print("{} \n".format(df2))

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)
print("{} \n".format(df3))
```

`df1` y `df2` son dataframes generados con decimales aleatorios de numpy, `df3` es la concatenación **horizontal** de estos dos. Los `print()` en el código muestran esto:

```
          A         B
0  0.214369  0.651027
1  0.005513  0.070687
2  0.037158  0.657393

          c         D
0  0.655054  0.668565
1  0.927045  0.492620
2  0.271781  0.198385

          A         B         C         D
0  0.214369  0.651027  0.655054  0.668565
1  0.005513  0.070687  0.927045  0.492620
2  0.037158  0.657393  0.271781  0.198385
```

**¿Qué hay del `axis = 0`?**

La única diferencias es que es una concatenación vertical, si se cambiara esta linea

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 0)
```

Siendo el argumentos `axis = 0`, se obtendría el siguiente dataframe por parte de `df3`:

```
          A         B         C         D
0  0.880407  0.886941       NaN       NaN
1  0.281703  0.197891       NaN       NaN
2  0.880959  0.095022       NaN       NaN
0       NaN       NaN  0.535670  0.700700
1       NaN       NaN  0.320057  0.574480
2       NaN       NaN  0.509887  0.638692
```

Esta concatenación vertical no es tan eficiente, en mi opnión `concat()` solo es útil con concatenaciones entre dataframes de la misma longitud y verticalmente. Si los dataframes no tuvieran las misma longitud

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2),columns = ["A","B"]) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,2),columns = ["C","D"])
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)
```

Se obtendrían algunos espacios con `NaN`:

```
          A         B         C         D
0  0.703573  0.902122  0.644335  0.576622
1  0.594446  0.636661  0.014517  0.286855
2  0.816604  0.742067       NaN       NaN
```

Espero te haya servido, saludos.